# Spring ResourceHandlerRegistry multipleLocations and performance

Tags: java, spring, performance

Dears,

I'm using 'Spring' for the backend and 'Polymer' for the frontend.
For the production bundles, I'm generating four 'frontend apps' based on user roles, using the same Spring backend.
Thus I have :

```
@Configuration 

public class StaticResourceConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    ...

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/bundled/app1/default/",
                "classpath:/static/bundled/app2/default/","classpath:/static/bundled/app3/default/","classpath:/static/bundled/app4/default/");
    }
}
```

as it might have to look on four different locations, might it have a significant impact on the performance ?

Comment: are you bothered only about performance, or do you have any other issue as well.

Comment: Only performance, it works fine

Answer (score 0):

1. Why don't you split the work for four different registries.
2. The more the specific the better is the performance.

Ideally, you should not hard code the path, instead have them as a dependency in your build path.

If possible initiate "each request in a new Thread". This can be done via `@RequiresNew`

Comment: Because they don't have a different endpoint.

The hardcoded paths are just for demo purpose. In real, it's coming from a property file

Comment: In that case I would prefer splitting them, and not have them loaded from a single point. Secondly, if possible initiate "each request in a new Thread". This can be done via @RequiresNew